# Android GridView add header from adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I managed to update the header View of adapters. listview, headerView (from listview), gridview within a single screen. the problem is due to listview and headerView display the same item, I want to hide the list view so as not to appear. how can i do that?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    final Context gridContext = rootView.getContext();
    gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);

    this.inflaterGeneral = inflater;
    headerView = inflaterGeneral.inflate(R.layout.cell_fragment_home_header_list, null);
    listViewHeader = (ListView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.listViewHeader);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    return rootView;
}
```

My Imageadapter

```
class ImageAdapterHeader extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    private TextView t;

    public ImageAdapterHeader(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        final Item i = itemVideo.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            final VideoDetail ei = (VideoDetail) i;

            //begin
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_fragment_home_header, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.imgThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
                holder.txtDuration = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                holder.txtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
                holder.txtComment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtComment);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtDuration.setText(ei.getDuration());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(ei.getTitle());
            holder.txtView.setText(ei.getViewCount());
            holder.txtComment.setText(ei.getLikeCount());

            Picasso.with(this.context)
                    .load(ei.getDetailPreview().replace(" ", "%20"))
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(holder.imgThumbnail);

            holder.imgThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), VideoPlayerActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("videoId", ei.getVideoId());
                            intent.putExtra("title", ei.getTitle());
                            intent.putExtra("artistName", ei.getArtistName());
                            intent.putExtra("view", ei.getViewCount());
                            intent.putExtra("like", ei.getLikeCount());
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item Null");
        }
        //end
        return convertView;
    }
```

Fragment home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<in.srain.cube.views.GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:background="#d9d8d8" >
    </in.srain.cube.views.GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter>
```

cell Fragment home header list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d9d8d8"
        android:scrollingCache="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Cell Fragment Home header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/jen4d" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPlay"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_play"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/button_play" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtDuration"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/xtName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="3:20"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparan"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/xtName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtDuration"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:text="Klepek - Klepek Versi Dance &apos;Dangduters&apos;"
                android:textColor="#ff8a65" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:text="Janeta Janet"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="25dp"  >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_white_24dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="10000"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="19dp"
                        android:layout_height="19dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_white_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtComment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="10000"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can I see your layout xml?

Comment: @MinhBui i want to make like this  gridView.addHeaderView(ListView); .. can you give me some advice ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[HeaderGridView][1]`, it subclass of `GridView`. I hope it helps.